# Requests module ideal chunk size for large files?

Tags: python, download, python-requests, iterator

I am working with the requests library to stream some large file and download , I want to set the chunk size to 1MB . so i am setting the chunk_size to 1000000 because 10^6 bytes should be 1 megabyte,
but i am getting unexpected results like:

```
import requests
import time
url="https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mp4/sample_3840x2160.mp4"
def dlprogress(url):
    a=1
    r=requests.get(url,stream=True,allow_redirects=True)
    f=open("demo.download",'wb')
    for ch in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1000000):
        if ch:
            f.write(ch)
            print(a,"mb downloaded")
            a=a+1
    f.close()
dlprogress(url)
```

I am getting results of "4525 mb downloaded" . the total iterations are  4525 ,
since i want to donwload large files upto 1GB what is the ideal chunk size for best speed , and i dont know why i am getting this result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ideal Chunk Size for python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369625/ideal-chunk-size-for-python-requests)

Comment: that question also doesn't have the answer, what i have figured out is that if the chunk size is set to bigger in iter_content than the chunk size sent by server , in that case the chunk is of maximum size . what we can acheive is receiving small chunk packets but not greater than sent by server . sorry for my english

Comment: I think selection of chunk size depends upon what you want in your RAM. If you have a RAM of 4 GB then a chunk size of 512 MB or 1 GB is okay. But if you have a RAM of 1 GB, then you probably don't want a chunk size of 1 GB. So you should set your `chunk_size` in accordance to available memory.